# Python how to find exact match in a list and not just contained in a word within list

Tags: python

I'm trying to find an exact match for a word in a list of words either in a `[]` list or a list from a text document separated by a word per line. But using `in` returns true if the word is contained in the list of words. I'm looking for an exact match. For example in python 2.7.12:

```
mylist = ['cathrine', 'joey', 'bobby', 'fredrick']

for names in mylist:
    if 'cat' in names:
        print 'Yes it is in list'
```

this will return true, but I i want it to only be true if it's an exact match. 'cat' should not return true if 'cathrine' is in mylist.

and trying to use `if 'cat' == names:` does't seem to work.

How would I go about returning true only if the string I'm looking for is an exact match of a list of words, and not contained within a word of a list of words?

Comment: if 'cat' in mylist -- doesn't seem to work or find anything. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `in` directly on the list.

**Ex:**

```
mylist = ['cathrine', 'joey', 'bobby', 'fredrick']

if 'cat' in mylist:
    print 'Yes it is in list'
#Empty


if 'joey' in mylist:
    print 'Yes it is in list'
#Yes it is in list
```

Comment: thanks, but i want it to return true only if its an exact match. so 'cat' shouldn't return true if a 'cathrine' is in there.

Comment: Yes cat will not return true in the above example

Comment: ok im reading from a text file of names. i've tried it on the raw text file (each name on a single line) and this doenst seem to work. i've tried converted the file...with open('mylist.txt', 'r') as infile: for names in infile: mylist.append(names) ....and using if 'cat' in mylist, and it doesnt return true if i use 'cahtrine'. am i missing something?

Comment: probably you have a trailing space in the text. Use `mylist.append(names.strip())`

Comment: `'cahtrine'`  spelling typo?

Comment: yeah, there are hard returns \n after the names when i print them. let me try that

Comment: yes thank you! the strip() method worked. i guess the hard returns \n in the list is what was messing it up.

Comment: just out of curiosity, why would a hard return \n after a name, lets say 'cathrine\n' return true if searching for 'cat', and return not true for 'cathrine'?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `in` with `if else` conditional operator

```
In [43]: mylist = ['cathrine', 'joey', 'bobby', 'fredrick']

In [44]: 'yes in list ' if 'cat' in mylist else 'not in list'
Out[44]: 'not in list'
```

Answer (score 1):

[@Rakesh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/532312/rakesh) Has given a answer to archive you task, This is just to make a correction to your statement.

```
 trying to use "if 'cat' == names:' does't seem to work
```

actually  `'cat' == names` this returns `false` the thing is your are missing the else part to catch that

```
mylist = ['cathrine', 'joey', 'bobby', 'fredrick']

for names in mylist:
    if 'cat' == names:
        print ('Yes it is in list')
    else:
        print('not in list')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `==` instead of `in`

```
mylist = ['cathrine', 'joey', 'bobby', 'fredrick']

for names in mylist:
    if names =='cat' :
        print('Matched')
    else:
        print('Not Matched')
```

I think it will work!